# dateRangePicker not working properly on jqGrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, daterangepicker

I have one jqgrid where one of the column say 'UpdateTime' is. I am applying filter on that and getting one DateRangePicker popup perfectly using below code.

```
{name:'updateTime',index:'updateTime',width:90,hidden:false,search:true,align:'center',stype:"text", 
    searchoptions:{dataInit:function(el){
        $(el).daterangepicker({ 
        dateFormat:'mm/dd/yy', 
        beforeShow: function(input, inst) {
            $.datepicker._pos = $.datepicker._findPos(input); 
            $.datepicker._pos[0] = center; 
            $.datepicker._pos[1] = center; 
        }, 
       onClose: function(event) {
         jQuery("#myGrid").trigger("reloadGrid");
       }                                                 
     });
    } 
   }
  },
```

I have

```
$("#myGrid").jqGrid('filterToolbar', {autoSearch:true,searchOnEnter:true});
```

The issue is, on selection of date(s) that filter's textbox is getting populated with the value(s) but control is not coming to my java code. Instead, I have to select the filter textbox again and hit the enter. And by next time onwards on selection of date(s) from daterangepicker popup,  control comes to my java code but not with the latest values. To get the latest value I have to hit the enter everytime.

So, is there any way to call my controller on selection of dates or can I auto focus my filter textbox, after date(s) selection, so that I'll hit enter every time. I am fine with hitting enter.

I tried with below code as well

```
onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
    $("#myGrid")[0].trigger("reloadGrid");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to solve this issue currently and I found this:

There are no onSelect, onClose event handlers in daterangepicker. And you have to update jqGrid filters manually before reload. My solution that works for me (evet if it looks like hack) is this.

```
    grid = jQuery("<table>").attr('id', myId+"_grid");
    var datePick = function(elem)
    {
       jQuery(elem).daterangepicker({
           dateFormat:"MM/DD/YYYY"
       });
       jQuery(elem).on('apply.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
            var d = picker.startDate.format('MM/DD/YYYY') + ' - ' + picker.endDate.format('MM/DD/YYYY');
            var f = {groupOp:"AND",rules:[]};
            f.rules.push({field:"time_submit",op:"eq",data:d});
            grid[0].p.search = true;
            jQuery.extend(grid[0].p.postData,{filters:JSON.stringify(f)});
            grid.trigger("reloadGrid",[{page:1,current:true}]);
        });
    }
```

Note: field stype is 'text' and you have to parse input string in format 'MM/DD/YYYY - MM/DD/YYYY'
Source: [Events of daterangepicker](https://github.com/dangrossman/bootstrap-daterangepicker#events)